# Seeking info on a Simchas Tora song

Tags: song-poetry, provenance, simchat-torah

While dancing on *Simchas Tora*, people sing a song with the following lyrics (except that I may very well have some of them wrong):

> אַשְׁרֵינוּ מַה טּוֹב חֶלְקֵנוּ
>   וּמַה נָּעִים גוֹרָלֵנוּ
>   אַשְׁרֵינוּ מַה טּוֹב חֶלְקֵנוּ
>   וּמַה יָּפָה יְרוּשָׁתֵנוּ
>   בְּדֶגֶל אֲגֻדָּה בְּאוֹר הַתּוֹרָה
>   כִּי טוֹב סַחְרָהּ מִכָּל סְחוֹרָה
>   כִּי טוֹב סַחְרָהּ מִכָּל סְחוֹרָה
>   חַיִּים בָּנוּ עֹז וְאוֹרָה
>   חַיִּים בָּנוּ עֹז וְאוֹרָה
>   בְּדֶגֶל אֲגֻדָּה בְּאוֹר הַתּוֹרָה

(I've hardly ever heard it other than on *Simchas Tora*.) Does anyone know the song's correct words, or its provenance (lyricist, composer, date, etc.)?

Comment: The first few lines (אַשְׁרֵינוּ מַה טּוב חֶלְקֵנוּ וּמַה נָּעִים גּורָלֵנוּ וּמַה יָּפָה יְרֻשָּׁתֵנוּ) can be found in the Korbanos in the beginning of Shacharis, shortly after the Akeidas Yitzchak, and right before the Shema.

Comment: I've heard Pirchei Boys Choir sing this. Eilecha, A Time For Music 2.

Comment: @Scimonster See [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49261/5323) ;-)

Comment: @Shokhet: Scimonster's comment preceded my answer.

Comment: @GershonGold I know. I thought it would be nice for him to see the follow-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This song was on Pirchei volume 2 - Aleicha Hashem is the tape title. [Here is a link where you can request to hear the song](http://jewishbroadcast.com/album/4597/best-of-pirchei). This tape was produced by Rabbi Eli Teitelbaum Zatzal in 5731/1971. The choir director was Eli Lipsker. The soloist on the song was Yechiel Moskovitz. There is no mention of the composer of the songs, and per my e-mail communication with Dovid Teitelbaum & Rabbi Baruch Chait the composer is unknown.

,בדגל אגודה באור התורה, כי טוב סחרה מכל סחורה
,וחיים לנו עוז ואורה, בדגל אגודה באור התורה

אַשְׁרֵינוּ מַה טּוֹב חֶלְקֵנוּ
וּמַה נָּעִים גוֹרָלֵנוּ
אַשְׁרֵינוּ מַה טּוֹב חֶלְקֵנוּ
וּמַה יָּפָה יְרוּשָׁתֵנוּ

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Pirchei-Choir-Sings-RARE-Chassidic-Jewish-Israeli-Israel-LP-/160754739873?_trksid=p2054897.l4275

Comment: Many thanks! I wonder still, though, whether the song was original to that album or it used an older song.